# filter by category work not properly with remote search?

Tags: meteor, vue.js, element-ui

Hello I have problem compute vue filter by category it work not properly when I add item on **Service** tab and then click on **Medicine** tab remote search item by category it will stuck and filter not work and when I click in **Service** tab back it show only number **2**.

[image]

this my template

```
<el-table
    :data="itemFilters"        
    row-key="no"
    style="width: 100%"
  >
```

This my script

```
computed: {    
 itemFilters() {
   const self = this
   let item = self.form.items.filter(o => {
    return o.categoryName === self.tabActive || o.itemId === ''
   })
   return item
 },
},
```

this Method

```
methods: {
  _getItemOpts(query, type) {
  let exp = new RegExp(query)

  let selector = {
    $or: [
      { name: { $regex: exp, $options: 'i' } },
      { refNo: { $regex: exp, $options: 'i' } },
      { barcode: { $regex: exp, $options: 'i' } },
    ],
    activityType: { $in: ['Sale'] },
    status: 'Active',
    'catDoc.name': this.tabActive,
  }

  // For form Sale Return and receipts refund
  if (this.formName == 'Sale_Return' || this.formName == 'Receipt_Refund') {
    selector.itemType = { $ne: 'Bundle' }
  }

  findItems
    .callPromise({ selector: selector })
    .then(result => {
      // this.itemOpts = result
      if (type == 'remote') {
        // For remote
        this.form.items[this.activeIndex].itemOpts = result
      } else {
        // For scan barcode
        let item = result[0]
        if (item) {
          let row = {
            itemId: item._id,
            itemType: item.itemType,
            memo: '',
            qty: 1,
            qtyRate: 1,
            unitId: item.units[0].unitId,
            units: item.units,
            price: item.price,
            amountBeforeDiscount: item.price,
            discountRate: 0,
            discountValue: 0,
            amountAfterDiscount: item.price,
            taxId: '',
            taxAmount: 0,
            // For expand bundle item
            subItems: [],
            expand: 'expand',
            // For sales only(cash sales and invoice)
            // refSaleOrderId: '',
            // refSaleOrderDetailId: '',
            // refNo: '',
            itemOpts: result,
          }

          this.form.items.push(row)
        } else {
          Notify.warning({ message: 'This item do not set barcode!' })
        }
      }

      this.loading = false
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.loading = false
      this.$notify.error(err.reason)
    })
  },
}
```

Please help...

Comment: I'm not sure where the field `tabActive` is defined.  Can you clarify?  Don't you mean `self.label` or `self.name`?

Comment: **tabActive**  can be Service , Medicine, Laboratory and Paraclinique

Comment: without knowing where you change tabActive, it's hard to tell what's wrong. Maybe you can include a more comprehensive example?  codesandbox.io is a good place to set up a quick vue.js project...